# What code to use in copying the workbook, removing all macros (including form controls), and pasting to another New Workbook w/o removing formula?

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I created a workbook that is automated with macro and I want to copy the whole workbook and paste it into another workbook and remove all macro's (including the form controls) except only the formulas.

My code is working copying the workbook and pasting to another workbook (including the formulas) and removing the macros. But the Form controls were still keep on appearing in the new workbook. What code do I need to add? Please help me. My code is written below:

```
            Private Sub Label16_Click()
              Unload Me
               Dim NewWkb As Workbook
               Dim xWkb As Workbook
               Dim x As Integer

                Set xWkb = Workbooks("Technical Support Database (Automated by MACRO).xlsb")
                Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add
                NewWkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\TSJeddah\OneDrive - Delta Marketing Co\JIM FILES\Operation Files\" & "TS Database (No MACRO).xlsx"
                For x = 1 To xWkb.Worksheets.Count - 1
xWkb.Sheets(x).Copy after:=NewWkb.Worksheets(NewWkb.Worksheets.Count)
                Next x 
              End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `save as` .XLSX-file work (non-macro workbook)?

Comment: yes it should be save in .xlsx file. That's why the form control (shape/object) must be deleted also, but in my script only the macros are deleted. The shape/Object still remain when I run it.

Comment: But if you save it as .XLSX you get prompted that the file contains macros that won't operate if you save as .XLSX and will be removed. Did you check this?

Comment: yes I already did. so you mean, If I will save it in .xlxb or xlm file there is a chance that form control (Shape/Objects) will also be deleted or remove? What I am trying to do is I want to remove also the form controls and save it to non-macro file or xlsx file.

Comment: I can't reproduce as I'm using the app version of Excel (Android app). But try it out and you'll see if it works or not. All VBA should be gone after saving as .xlsx

Comment: no problem, once I found the solution. I will update and share this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove all form controls from the target workbook, you can do so with the following code:

```
Sub DeleteFormControlsFromWB(WB As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Shape, ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In WB.Worksheets
        For Each sh In ws.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoFormControl Or sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
                Debug.Print "Deleted Form control: " & sh.Name    'debug
                sh.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub UsageExample()
    DeleteFormControlsFromWB ThisWorkbook
End Sub
```

Comment: You may have ActiveX controls on your workbook sheets instead of Form controls

Comment: @mijnivek see updated code - included `Or sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject` into the condition for ActiveX controls detection

Answer (score 0):

```
         Private Sub Label16_Click()
          Unload Me
           Dim NewWkb As Workbook
           Dim xWkb As Workbook
           Dim x As Integer

            Set xWkb = Workbooks("Technical Support Database (Automated by 
            MACRO).xlsb")
            Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add
            NewWkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\TSJeddah\Desktop\JIM\" & "TS Database (No 
            MACRO).xlsx"
            Call UsageExample
            For x = 1 To xWkb.Worksheets.Count - 1
            xWkb.Sheets(x).Copy 
            after:=NewWkb.Worksheets(NewWkb.Worksheets.Count)
           Next x
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         End Sub
```